# How to implement Word2Vec in Java?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, word2vec

I installed word2Vec [using this tutorial](http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-word2vec-and-glove) on by Ubuntu laptop. Is it completely necessary to install [DL4J](http://deeplearning4j.org) in order to implement word2Vec vectors in Java? I'm comfortable working in Eclipse and I'm not sure that I want all the other pre-requisites that DL4J wants me to install.

Ideally there would be a really easy way for me to just use the Java code I've already written (in Eclipse) and change a few lines -- so that word look-ups that I am doing would retrieve a word2Vec vector instead of the current retrieval process I'm using.

---

Also, I've looked into using GloVe, however, I do not have MatLab. Is it possible to use GloVe without MatLab? (I got an error while installing it because of this). If so, the same question as above goes... I have no idea how to implement it in Java.

Comment: Actually I was building a small Glove library in Java, maybe worth putting it on GitHub.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut there seem to be a small handful of word2vec/Glove libraries on Git, but I don't know much about them at all... Please let me know more if you decide to upload it!

Comment: Depends on what you need, is it just word to a vector lookup or do you need traversal?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut At the moment, I wanted to first experiment with look-up. Scanning words from a file and retrieving a vector for each.

Comment: I mean it's fairly easy to parse the glove text files and just put it into a map in memory, is the size an issue for you? (the stuff I wrote pages to disk and loads on demand)

Comment: I have a fairly large set of data I want to convert into vectors. I have 0 experience with glove or word2vec, so I'm working on a bit of a learning curve right now.

Comment: Cool, let me work on some more test cases and documentation and I'll let you know here once I released it to github- might be useful for you

Comment: there you go: https://github.com/thomasjungblut/glove I will add tests over the next days to harden it

Comment: Awesome, looks great! The only thing I'm not familiar with is the "fat jar (glove*-shaded.jar)"?

Comment: Execute `mvn package` and find it under `/target`, it needs maven to build if you know how to use it

Comment: @ThomasJungblut  the glove-vectors.txt refers to the vectors.txt that GloVe (c file) produces when it runs, correct?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut is there a way in your library to save the word vector to an array? Like double hold[] = db.get("man"); ?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Also, is there a way to check if the word was not found in the db? I've gotten some null-pointer errors

Comment: @jonbon if(word != null){ //not null } else {null}

Comment: @jonbon there is a `toArray` method in the vector class. In the DB there is a `contains` method, what Nate told you to check works as well.

Answer (score 9):

Dl4j author here. Our word2vec implementation is targeted  for people who need to have custom pipelines. I don't blame you for going the simple route here.

Our word2vec implementation is meant for when you want to do something with them not for messing around. The c word2vec format is pretty straight forward.

Here is parsing logic in java if you'd like:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/374609b2672e97737b9eb3ba12ee62fab6cfee55/deeplearning4j-scaleout/deeplearning4j-nlp/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/models/embeddings/loader/WordVectorSerializer.java#L113

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: I tried DL4J, its too heavy. Do you have a lighter version that only deals with w2vec?

Comment: Could you define "too heavy"? Sorry but it's a general purpose framework. Everything from the tokenizers to the way you input data is pluggable. That's on purpose. People use dl4j to solve real problems. They have special requirements.  It's only a few dependencies to include. deeplearning4j-nlp and nd4j-native-platform. The rest is on you to do. I can be helpful if you're more specific but "too heavy" isn't useful critique in any form.

Answer (score 8):

What is preventing you from saving the word2vec (the C program) output in text format and then read the file with a Java piece of code and load the vectors in a hashmap keyed by the word string?

Some code snippets:

```
// Class to store a hashmap of wordvecs
public class WordVecs {

    HashMap<String, WordVec> wordvecmap;
    ....
    void loadFromTextFile() {
        String wordvecFile = prop.getProperty("wordvecs.vecfile");
        wordvecmap = new HashMap();
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(wordvecFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                WordVec wv = new WordVec(line);
                wordvecmap.put(wv.word, wv);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }        
    }
    ....
}

// class for each wordvec
public class WordVec implements Comparable<WordVec> {
    public WordVec(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        word = tokens[0];
        vec = new float[tokens.length-1];
        for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++)
            vec[i-1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[i]);
        norm = getNorm();
    }
    ....
}
```

If you want to get the nearest neighbours for a given word, you can keep a list of N nearest pre-computed neighbours associated with each WordVec object.